# After Khul'a: How can husband and wife reconcial -if they want to?

Tags: fiqh, talaq, iddah

In case that Khul'a الخلع happened and the wife and husband have legally been separated, but want to get back together. I assume that there's no turning back (reconciliation) within the 'Iddah as it would be the case for talaq.

Nevertheless on this topic there are two different views one setting khul'a "equal to talaq" (divorce) and another setting it "equal to faskh" (invalidation) as I've learnt from [What is the period of iddah after Khula?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35273/what-is-the-period-of-iddah-after-khula). So there might be at least two different opinions one whether or not a reconciliation is not permissible.

I'd like to have an answer addressing the possibly different fiqh views on this:

- Is it allowed to reconcile during the 'Iddah?
- If not is it allowed to re-marry during the 'Iddah or must they wait?