# Khula: Iddat conditions

Tags: iddah

Assalaamu Alaykum. If a woman has not been intimate with her husband for more than six months and is seeking khula does she still need to do Iddat? If she does iddat is it, only until the completion of her menstrual cycle?

Comment: Iddah is required even if the couple had separated beforehand, see [Is Iddah required if the couple has been seperate for a time before divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34996). As for the period of iddah after Khula' it is disagreed upon, some hold that it is three menstrual cycles (or three months if a woman does not menstruate) while others hold that it is only one menstrual cycle, see [What is the period of iddah after Khula?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35273/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the period of iddah after Khula?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35273/what-is-the-period-of-iddah-after-khula)